# Jupyter Notebook refusing to print some strings

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Some print() outputs are being dropped in my notebook, but I can't see any particular pattern or reason:

```
s = 'https://ad.doubleclick.net/'
t = 'ttps://ad.doubleclick.net/'
u = 'https://ad.doubleclick.net'
v = 'https://ad.doublclick.net/'
w = 'https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?caps'

for string in [s, t, u, v]:
    print('str:', string)
    print('repr(str):', repr(string))
    print()
```

Outputs:

```
str: 
repr(str): 'https://ad.doubleclick.net/'

str: ttps://ad.doubleclick.net/
repr(str): 'ttps://ad.doubleclick.net/'

str: https://ad.doubleclick.net
repr(str): 'https://ad.doubleclick.net'

str: https://ad.doublclick.net/
repr(str): 'https://ad.doublclick.net/'

str: 
repr(str): 'https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?caps'
```

What happened to my first and last `str:` lines??
Only happens in notebooks, running python interpreter in the terminal does not have this issue.

Python 3.8.5

```
> which jupyter
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/jupyter

> jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.0.0
ipykernel        : 6.7.0
ipywidgets       : 7.7.1
jupyter_client   : 7.1.1
jupyter_core     : 4.9.1
jupyter_server   : not installed
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.5.10
nbconvert        : 6.4.0
nbformat         : 5.1.3
notebook         : 6.4.7
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.1.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly an answer, but this is a result of Jupyter notebook checking if string variables are URLs and if so, making them into clickable links in the output area. The output of your cell is rendered inside a `<pre>` tag and looks like this:

```
<pre>
str: <a target="_blank" href="https://ad.doubleclick.net/">https://ad.doubleclick.net/</a>
repr(str): 'https://ad.doubleclick.net/'

str: ttps://ad.doubleclick.net/
repr(str): 'ttps://ad.doubleclick.net/'

str: <a target="_blank" href="https://ad.doubleclick.net">https://ad.doubleclick.net</a>
repr(str): 'https://ad.doubleclick.net'

str: <a target="_blank" href="https://ad.doublclick.net/">https://ad.doublclick.net/</a>
repr(str): 'https://ad.doublclick.net/'

str: <a target="_blank" href="https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?caps">https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?caps</a>
repr(str): 'https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?caps'
</pre>
```

Now the fact that some of the links don't appear is not a Jupyter notebook issue, you can try render this HTML on a site like https://html.onlineviewer.net and see the same issue. But for me this issue occurs only in Firefox, not in two other browsers I checked (Safari and Chrome). Since I couldn't find any discussion of this behaviour, I opened up a ticket on Bugzilla [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1785194).

Comment: That is some admirable sleuthing, Josh. Thanks! Nice work!

Comment: Update from the Bugzilla thread: this was caused by an ad-blocking extension (in my case uBlock Origin), which hides links to ad-serving domains like doubleclick.net https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1785194